# Issue while autowiring strongly typed collections

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am using spring 3.2.2. I am facing issue while autowring the collection by spring's byType autowiring mode. I have created the below example.

Bean defination:

```
package com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @author jinesh
 *
 */
public class Address {

    ArrayList<Country> country;

    public ArrayList<Country> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(ArrayList<Country> country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

Below is the spring configuration file testmultidimensionalcollection.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="addressMiddleEast" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Address" autowire="byType">

    </bean> 

    <bean id="countryChina" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="China" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryIndia" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="India" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryAus" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="Australia" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="middeastcountryQuatar" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="Quatar" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="middeastcountryIsrael" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="Israel" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="middeastcountryYemen" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="Yemen" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Here I have strong type collection in the Address class. So all the elements of the country are supposed to be added inside the Country properties arraylist but when I am executing the below code I am getting the Null pointer exception.

```
package com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * @author jinesh
 *
 */

public class TestMultiDimensionalMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springaction/testmultidimesionalcollection/testmultidimensionalcollection.xml");
        Address addrs=(Address)context.getBean("addressMiddleEast");
        System.out.println("address size:" + addrs.getCountry().size());
   }
}
```

I am not able to understand, why spring is not able to automatically detect the country beans and add them to the array list property of address bean? Have I missed something in the configuration?

Comment: 'I am getting the Null pointer exception.' Where? At which line?

Comment: The line at which I am trying to obtain the country collection.Below addrs.getCountry.size()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually requested that anything be autowired. This bean

```
<bean id="addressMiddleEast" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Address" autowire="byType">
</bean>
```

and class

```
public class Address {

    ArrayList<Country> country;

    public ArrayList<Country> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(ArrayList<Country> country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

simply has property setters/getters. You need to use `@Autowired` (or the related annotations).

```
public class Address {
    @Autowired
    ArrayList<Country> country;
```

If you can't use `@Autowired` (why not???), you would need to create a bean of type `List` that has a reference to each of your `Country` beans, like in (now deleted) tichodrama's answer.

This is explained in the Spring IoC documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Comment: But i am not using annotation based spring configuration? Do I need to use this to make the to autowiring works ?

Comment: @Bean You can't autowire beans if you don't use the `@Autowired`, `@Inject`, or `@Resource` annotations. Using non-annotation based configuration, you have to explicitly wire beans. So you either use `@Autowired` and let Spring do it, or you specify a `List` of countries as a bean and use that in the `<property>` element for your bean.

Comment: :I am still facing the same issue. I have added the below code in my spring configuration file. But stil it is giving me the same error.      <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" id="countryLst">
  <list>
   <ref bean="countryChina"/>
   <ref bean="countryIndia"/>
   <ref bean="countryAus"/>
  </list>
 </util:list>

Comment: :Thanks for all your help. I was able to resolve the issue as per the changes suggested by you. I just need to change to the List interface instead of using the implementation of List interface and use the Autowired annontation.                          List<Country> country; 
public List<Country> getCountry() {
  return country;
}